# How do i change default SSH2 port in ECLIPSE?

Tags: ssh, eclipse

I'd like to change the default SSH2 port in Eclipse from 22 to another one. I try to define the host like host:55 (if using 55 for SSH2) and no luck.

Any tip?

Comment: What do you mean by "SSH2 port in Eclipse"? Eclipse is not an SSH server, so this makes no sense. Are you using some SSH plugin, or writing an SSH server?

Comment: I'm trying to connect with the Remote System Explorer plugin.
*back to coding with SmartFTP*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you have created your connection, go to the Remote Systems Explorer(Window->Views->Remote Systems) right click on any one of the child items of the connection and select *Properties*.  In the properties window select the *Subsystem* group.  The port can be configured from this screen.

Comment: As you have Sftp Files and Ssh Shells, select Ssh Shells -> right click Properties and Subsystem. There it is:)